# Why is n = (-2)?

Tags: calculus

Recently I've been working on refreshing my calculus skills. In my review of integration, I came upon this problem:

$$\int\frac{9}{(t-8)^2}dt$$

It stumped me, so I inputted it into an [integral calculator.](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) I understand most of the output, but there's one bit that I don't understand.

Starting from here:
$$9\int\frac{1}{u^2}du, u=(t-8)$$
it says to apply the power rule with $n=-2$ to get
$$9\int-\frac{1}{u}$$

My question is, why does $n=-2$? It appears to me that it should be 3 ($2+1$).

Comment: $\frac{1}{u^2}=u^{-2}$.

Comment: I assume there are different conventions either saying the power rule is for $n=-2$ because that's what is being integrated or saying it is for $n=-3$ because you get it from differentiating $1/x^{-3}$.

Comment: "*So I inputted it into an integral calculator*" Be warned that most online calculators that try to market themselves to students are rubbish.  It is far better to actually learn the material.  As for the power rule, you should have learned that $\int x^n~dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}+C$ and similarly that $\frac{d}{dx}[x^n] = n\cdot x^{n-1}$.  It was written very specifically with $x$'s in the numerator there, not the denominator.  If you wish to use this here, then move the $u$ to the numerator using basic facts involving negative exponents to rewrite as $\int u^{-2}~du$

Comment: @JMoravitz maybe you are right, but I don’t think [this one](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) is rubbish. I actually got to know Ostrogradsky’s method from here first. (Note: this is not to promote any website, I am not affiliated with the linked website in any form whatsoever).